# Why laravel query is not fetching right data?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to get records having mode `easy` and `advanced` but it's returning only `easy` records each time. i.e Those records having mode set to easy.

**Query string:** mywebsite.com/game?easy=easy&advanced=advanced

```
public function index(Request $request) {

    if($request->has('easy') {
        return GameMode::where('mode', $request->easy)->get();
    }

    if($request->has('advanced') {
        return GameMode::where('mode', $request->advanced)->get();
    }

    return GameMode::all();
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up; don't post "Thank you" comments; if the answers below are helpful, give them an upvote, and select one as the answer (which you've done, thanks for that)

Comment: sure @TimLewis I should thank you for the advice :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning the query with mode set to easy immediately if it's set. What you could do is build your query based on your request like this:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $query = GameMode::query();

    if ($request->has('easy')) {
        $query->where('mode', $request->easy);
    }

    if ($request->has('advanced')) {
        $query->orWhere('mode', $request->advanced);
    }

    return $query->get();
}
```

Comment: what about `$request->has('easy')` is false case??

Comment: @Davit Doesn't matter. The query would just proceed without the `mode = 'easy'`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

This means you have to create an empty query and then build it based on the inputs:

```
public function index(Request $request) {

    $query = GameMode::query();
    if($request->has('easy') {
        $query->where('mode', $request->easy);
    }

    if($request->has('advanced') {
        $query->orWhere('mode', $request->advanced);
    }

    return $query->get();
}
```

Refer to [this article](https://m.dotdev.co/writing-advanced-eloquent-search-query-filters-de8b6c2598db) for more info.

Comment: what about $request->has('easy') is false case??

Comment: I don't think `andWhere` is right; you can't have a single row with both modes; `WHERE mode = 'easy' AND mode = 'advanced'` won't work. `whereIn` or `orWhere` are correct.

Comment: Thank you, @Davit and @TimLewis. I've edited the answer. You are right. If you want to have modes `easy` AND `advanced` you need to use `orWhere`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

try to used `when` method here

```
return GameMode::when($request->easy,function($q,$request) {
             return $q->where('mode', $request->easy);
       })->when($request->advanced,function($q,$request) {
             return $q->orWhere('mode', $request->advanced);
       })->get();
```

Comment: This will return no result in his scenario. The mode is either easy or advanced. You need to use `orWhere`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great answer.

Answer (score 3):

Solution 1:

```
public function index(Request $request) {
    if($request->only('easy','advanced')) {
        return GameMode::whereIn('mode', $request->only('easy','advanced'))->get();
    }

    return GameMode::all();
}
```

solution 2:

```
public function index(Request $request) {

    if($request->has('easy') && $request->has('advanced')) {
        return GameMode::whereIn('mode', [$request->easy, $request->advanced])->get();
    }

    if($request->has('mode')) {
        return GameMode::where('mode', $request->easy)->get();
    }

    if($request->has('advanced')) {
        return GameMode::where('mode', $request->advanced)->get();
    }

    return GameMode::all();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

In these scenarios I try to use `scope*` functions

 
`GameMode.php` model

```php
...
public function scopeEasyMode($q, $easy) 
{
    if (!empty($easy)) { return $q->orWhere('mode', $easy); }
}

public function scopeAdvanceMode($q, $adv) 
{
    if (!empty($adv)) { return $q->orWhere('mode', $adv); }
}
...
```

In your controller `GameModeController.php`

```php
...
$results = GameMode::easyMode($request->easy)->advanceMode($request->advance)->get();
...
```

This will filter out your **required modes** or **all**

Update: Rather than passing the value directory to those `scope*` methods rather you better filter/validate values first which is less error-prone.